# Property changing null whilst updating a value

Tags: linq-to-sql

i am retreiveing the  Data object through a class which is partial class in linq to sql.

i am using the same object model to update the changes. but proprertychanging is always null for this object.

An anonoymous type has been converted into  strong object type. This strong type is updated again.

---

Can anyone explain the reason for this?

## Sample Code:

```
var questions = from Question in _db.QuestionDataSource
                            join AnswerType in _db.AnswerTypeDataSource on Question.IN_AnswerTypeId equals AnswerType.IN_AnswerTypeId
                            join Section in _db.SectionDataSource on 
........
                            orderby Section.IN_Order,Question.VC_Code  

                            select new
                            {
                                Question.UI_QuestionID,
                                Question.VC_Description,

                            }; 

----------

ICollection<ICheckListInstanceQuestion> checkListQuestions = new 
List<ICheckListInstanceQuestion>();
        foreach (var question in questions)
        {
            checkListQuestions.Add(new CheckListInstanceQuestion
            {

                UI_QuestionID = question.UI_QuestionID,

                VC_Description = question.VC_Description,



            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
the object which created is localized one and it  needs to be attached into original object.
```